# Declaring a variable stops the function in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a projects database using google sheets and Apps Script.

I have developed the code below to add a new record page (sheet) every time a new record/project is added to the projects list sheet.

The strange thing is that the code works well but when I declare the variable `text` in line 11 the code doesn't work. Actually, the variable `text` is not even used in the code yet. it doesn't contribute to the code's logic.

Can anyone explain this to me, please?

```
// This module is to add a new project record page when a new project included in the Project List sheet

function addNewRecord(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Template");
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var cell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).getValue();
  var text = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Projects List').getRange(row,1).getCell(row,1);

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();  //creating an array or calling the existing sheets of the spreadsheet.

  var sheetsNames = [];        //creating an array of the existing sheets names

  for (let i =0 ; i < sheets.length; i++){
      
    sheetsNames[i] = sheets[i].getSheetName();

  }


  //checking the entered value contains LCE keyword and it's an actual new record
  if (sheetName === 'Projects List' && col ===1){
    
    if (cell.includes('LCE') && sheetsNames.indexOf(cell) === -1){

      sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(cell);
      ss.getSheetByName(cell).getRange(1,2).setValue(cell);
      
      function getSheetUrl() {
        var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var ss = SS.getSheetByName(cell);
        var url = '';
        url += SS.getUrl();
        url += '#gid=';
        url += ss.getSheetId();
        //Logger.log(url); 
        return url;
      }

      var value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(cell).setLinkUrl(getSheetUrl()).build();

      //e.source.getSheetByName('Projects List').getRange(row,1).getCell(row,1).setRichTextValue(value);

      //cellV.setRichTextValue(value);
      
    }
  }
//Logger.log(sheets);
}
```

Comment: post code rather an image and your error says it all that you should pass `UIImage` .. not `UIImageview`

Comment: Show us the definition of image variable. If image is a UIImageView then that's your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like your variable "image" is a UIImageView, not a UIImage. Replace this line

```
var myRGBA = RGBAImage(image: image)
```

with this

```
var myRGBA = RGBAImage(image: image.image)
```

This is because a UIImageView holds an image. To access it you must call UIImageView.image

For future reference, you should always copy and paste code, not posting a screenshot, so that other users can find questions easier through search engines, and users trying to answer your questions can replicate your issue by copying and pasting your code into their own environment.

Comment: Also, if `image` is a UIImageView, it shouldn't be named "image".